# How to convert between SQL Server schemas

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-schema, sql-server-2014

I want to convert my database schema that I created using SQL Server 2014 with file type `.mdf` to SQL Server 2008 with file type `.sdf`.

I formatted my laptop and SQL Server is removed with it. I'm wondering if there is a way or a small tool or website to convert the schema in one click without installing SQL Server Management Studio in my laptop.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 **ALSO** uses the `.mdf` data file format - the `.sdf` files are used by SQL Server **CE** (Compact Edition) which is a totally different product (embedded, stand-alone, single-user)

Comment: Yeah that what I'm trying to convert my Database to in order to be able to be installed on any other computer without the need of installing SQL server.

Comment: Then you need SQL Server **CE** (Compact Edition) - but unfortunately, that is no longer officially being developed by Microsoft anymore..... it works, but don't expect any bugfixes or new features anymore